# Replace large file with placeholder so backup program won't believe it's changed and will keep it uploaded

Tags: backup, ntfs

I'm using a program which will back everything up, but if you delete a file, it'll only store it on their servers for 30 days.

I'm just wondering if it would be possible to replace a file with a 1kb version, but still have the computer believe it's the same large file, so while I won't be able to load it, it wouldn't get deleted from the server either.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to backup a corrupt file?  What program are we talking about?  If its any of the major player's in this sector, they perform a hash on the file, so what you want is possible with those clients.

Answer (score 1):

No. The *1KB version* **is** *what would get backed up*, as soon as you replaced the real file with it. So you'd lose even the 30 days of retention (with many backup schemes - if they actually give you 30 days of "getting the old version back" rather than just the most recent backup, you'd have that.)